# How to set an attribute value where the attribute itself is variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview

I have a TableView with two columns - name and value where name is the attribute name itself for a class instance of an object from CoreData. And value is a textfield that is the value or that attribute and I want the user to be able to edit that in the tableview.

I have the property names and separately the values each stored in a separate array.  So I have propertyArray and valueArray and the order of the arrays matches the keyed pairs.

So with that, I can certainly determine which property is being edited based upon the IndexPath, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to change the actual property value to what is newly entered in the text field.

The logic is I need :

```
animal.(propertyArray[IndexPath.row]) = textField.text
```

is there a way for me to create a string variable of "animal.whateverTheAttributeIs" and to somehow convert that into the left hand part of that equation?

Comment: I assume you have only one instance of the core data entity in your table view and then x number of attributes, i.e rows, for that instance?

Comment: yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: Then you have the attributes in a certain order so you should create a simple mapping between row number and property.

Comment: yes, I have the data ordered properly.  I don't know about mapping so that is something I can research.  I'm able to get to all the individual points of data that I have to form the equation of setting the animal.property but how do I specify animal.x = "Spot" or animal.x = "Male" where x changes from row to row?  I have the literal string representation of x, but I don't know how to form that into the equation itself to set the new property value.

Comment: Use [`setValue:forKeyPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418139-setvalue).

Comment: thank you!! I just read the documentation for that at your suggestion and its exactly what I need!!

Answer (score 2):

You can have a dictionary that holds the mapping between row numbers and properties using KeyPath

```
struct Example {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var text: String
}

let rowMap: [Int: WritableKeyPath<Test, String>] = [0: \.id, 1: \.name, 2: \.text]
```

and then you do a look up in the dictionary to get the right key path from a row

```
if let keypath = rowMap[indexPath.row] {
    exampleObject[keyPath: keypath] = "some value"
}
```

or for an NSObject subclass (that your class is) you can use `setValue:forKeyPath` as mentioned in the comments

```
if let keypath = rowMap[indexPath.row] {
    exampleObject.setValue("some value", forKeyPath: keypath)
}
```

This is somewhat simplified since I assume from your examples that all properties are of type String